# With Python sqlite3, should I use sleep() after any SQL operation and commit()?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sleep, corruption

I was doing some scripted update to the sqlite database of Clementine media player (60,000 entries) and found that in the end the database was corrupted.

So I strongly suspected that it was that my write operations in the for-loop didn't have enough time to complete before next loop starts. I tested by time.sleep() for 2 seconds after my UPDATE call, and 15 seconds after my periodic commit(). This seems to work but the whole process became really slow. Sample code:

```
CommitInterval = 1000
artistCounter = 0
for artist in allArtists
    artistCounter += 1

    for record in albumRatings:
        album = record[0]
        rating = record[1]

        dbCursor.execute('UPDATE songs SET rating = ? WHERE LOWER(songs.artist) == ? AND   LOWER(songs.album) == ? AND rating < ?', (rating, artist, album, rating))

        # short sleep
        ShortSleepSec = 2
        time.sleep(ShortSleepSec)

    if artistCounter == CommitInterval:
        db.commit()
        artistCounter = 0

        # long sleep
        SleepSec = 15
        print 'Sleep %d seconds...' % (SleepSec)
        time.sleep(SleepSec)
```

Here are my questions:
Should I really sleep after both the UPDATE and commit() or just one of them?
How should I calculate how long I should sleep after these calls?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The whole DB thing would be really worthless when you had to so that to avoid subtle data corruption. You shouldn't have to `sleep` **at all**.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite doesn't need to sleep after a commit.  Sqlite is synchronous, in-process, so by the time commit() returns, the operation is completed.  But: it can be dangerous to use sqlite on more than one thread.

Comment: +1 -- What he's saying is that fast write operations *aren't* what's corrupting your data; the `sleep()` shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but

- you do not need to `sleep` between database operations
- you should not insert single records over and over

The `sqlite3` module provides you with `cursor.executemany()`. This will [heavily reduce runtime](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). Use it like so:

```
par = [ (row[1], artist, row[0], row[1]) for row in albumRatings ]
sql = 'UPDATE songs SET rating = ? WHERE LOWER(songs.artist) == ? AND   LOWER(songs.album) == ? AND rating < ?'
dbCursor.executemany(sql, par)
```

I would `db.commit()` immediately after that round.

Also, make sure that the media player does not access the database during the update process, aso not from some else invisible demon job.